# How to hide batch output

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am putting the finishing touches to a batch script that transfers the contents of a locally edited web site to the internet.

The script opens in a console window, and outputs quite a lot of stuff the administrator needs to see in case something goes wrong. In that case, though, the output is being sent as E-Mail, so there is no need to display the output and confuse the user who runs the update unnecessarily. I need to display only a few lines (say, "starting synchronisation..." and "syncrhonisation complete").

Can anybody think of a way to stop output in a batch script? Kind of a total "echo off"?

A simple

```
my_batch_file > nul
```

won't cut it, because as I said, a few things I need to show.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Windows actually does have the notion of stdout and stderr. Here's an example:

test.bat:

```
@echo off
echo verbose stuff 1
echo verbose stuff 2
echo verbose stuff 3
echo important stuff! >&2
echo verbose stuff 4
```

If you run it as '`test.bat`' you'll get the full output. If you run it as '`test.bat >nul`' then you'll only get the 'important' output (anything redirected to stderr, with the >&2)

Answer (score 11):

your batch script could run itself

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "1" goto else
echo start
call %0 1 > nul
echo done
goto done
:else:
echo do stuff
:done:
```

stdout of the second invocation goes to nul

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `>nul` is not enough. In my case I had to do `2>nul`. Example:

```
taskkill /im test.exe 2>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write the few things that need showing to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Or alternatively, redirect the outputs of the individual parts that you want hidden.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up my example, I am on a Windows system here. Doesn't work there does it?

Comment: Oh you're talking about a literal Batch file. In that case, you could separate the parts that you don't want showing into a separate Batch script, and call it from your primary one, redirecting the output. Also, keep in mind the `@` prefix, which stops the command itself from being printed.

Answer (score 0):

Combining `@` and `> NUL` worked for me, e.g.

`@FC [file1] [file2] > NUL`

hides both the command and it's output when executing a batch file.

This script did not stop the display of any error messages.